# Why even the width fit? it still drop below

Tags: html

**Try to make this:**
[image]

Article and Aside are the same width
I don't know if the floating is wrong, or other. even I make the margin to 0, the Article box will drop below to Aside. And I don't why after I float the box, some of the borderlines will overlap but the footer won't. And there are some requirements.
The border is 3px.
The height of each box is 200px. Article and Aside are the same width

```css
header,main,aside,article,footer{
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
}

main {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

aside{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

article {

    width: 20%;
    float: right;

}

footer{

    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h2>Header</h2>
</header >

<main>
    <h2>Main</h2>
</main>

<aside>
    <h2>Aside</h2>
</aside>

<article>
    <h2>Article</h2>
</article>

<footer>
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is not a question. Can you try to improve it? What drops down? Perhaps if you add the HTML we could get an idea?

Comment: Without it I would say: reduce the margin to zero: `margin: 0;` instead of `margin: 1em;`. Then could can add `padding: 1em;` to space the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the .main, .aside, .article blocks with a flex container.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.header,.main,.aside,.article,.footer{
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
}

.aside {
  width: 20%;
}

.article {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="main">MAIN</div>
      <div class="aside">ASIDE</div>
      <div class="article">ARTICLE</div>
    </div>

  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A way is using `grid`:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: green;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}

.main {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

.asid {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}

.article {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <div class="asid">asid</div>
  <div class="article">article</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex

```css
section{
  display: flex;
}

main, aside, article{
height: 60px;
}

main{
flex-grow: 3;
background: red;
}
aside{
flex-grow: 1;
background: green;
}
article{
flex-grow: 1;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <main>main</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <article>article</article>
  </section>
```